# Scenario to be implemented, think awk is the best for such situation

Tags: python, linux, shell, awk

I have the following scenario which i needed.

I have two very big files which have lines in crores, and the no. of lines in each file is same.
I think awk is the useful tool with which I can join the two files with some conditions incorporated into it. Please suggest.

```
File1
# header1, header2, header3, header4
1,2,3,4
11,12,13,14
21,22,23,24
31,32,33,34
41,42,43,44

File2
a   d  e  f
a   f  g  h
b   p  q
33  b  p  q
43  b  x  y

Final Output
1, 2, 3, 4, a, d, e, f
11, 12, 13, 14, a, f, g, h
21, 22, 23, 24, b, p, q
31, 32, 33, 34, b, p, q
41, 42, 43, 44, b, x, y
```

There is actually a connection between file1, file2. Few headers are collected from each line of file1, and based on some small tool file2 is generated. So for each line in file1, there is some information in the same line of file2. 
And now i wanted to join these two files, as below logic.

file2's first entry either contain 'a', 'b', or header 3 of file1
based on this if it contains 'a' or 'b' then we join the lines as is "1, 2, 3, 4, a, d, e, f"

if file2's entry has header3 of file1, then we join as is "31, 32, 33, b, p, q"

All the fields have to comma separated. And the output has to be dumped into other file.

I can do the same thing in python as well but it takes too much time in for loop processing, as the file is too big, and there is lot python interpretation time involves.. So I think awk would be better utility to do such task.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: your description seem a little (lot) confusing to me.To begin with you say that both files are comma sepperated, but your file2 is not.And, by lines in crores,you mean a large amount?(had to look crores up).What is more ,am I correct in saying that by header 1,header 2 etc you mean the numbers 1,2,3,4 or 11,12,13,14 etc?

Comment: Yes Correct... File1 contains one line which contains the headers of the rest of lines for each entry.

Comment: So, line2 of file1 corresponds to line1 of file2,, line3 of file1 corresponds to line2 of file2 and so on.

And we have to join according to the condition mentioned. Let me know if there is any other query.

Comment: Yes both the files are very big, so in order to process each file through pythonic loop and then creating a logic to join the files seems very time consuming.. so i went to awk for the better alternative, and think it will take less time..!!

Comment: Do you want to combine `File1` and `File2`? Can you post the result?

Comment: One more thing:What do you mean by _or header 3 of file1 based on this if it contains 'a' or 'b'_ ?

Comment: Can you post the python code you're using?

Comment: kev: updated the post, contains the final result

Comment: byrondrossos: if value of header3 in file1, is contained in first col of file2 then we don't print value of header3 two times while joining. hope i am able to explain it. rest you can see the final output which i have updated in the post.

Comment: Is the third line of file2 really only supposed to have three fields? Are the output fields supposed to be comma-separated, or separated by a comma and a space?

Comment: Michael. the output_field should be separated by comma only.. which is correct that you did.
and file2 can have 3 or 4 or 5 fields depending on the 1 field that it has.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea should be to join the lines together with `paste`, then correct for the duplicated header using `awk`.

I'm assuming that `file2` has tab-separated fields. Try this pipeline:

```
grep -v '^#' file1.csv \
| tr ',' '\t' \
| paste - file2.tsv \
| awk -v OFS="," '
    $3==$5 { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6,$7,$8; next } 
    { $1=$1; print }'
```

With the sample data provided, this produces:

```
1,2,3,4,a,d,e,f
11,12,13,14,a,f,g,h
21,22,23,24,b,p,q
31,32,33,34,b,p,q
41,42,43,44,b,x,y
```

Comment: Please explain this command, as I am little aware of awk utility.

Answer (score 1):

```
paste -d, <(tail -n+2 File1) <(awk -vOFS=, '
{
    $1 = ($1 !~ /^(a|b)$/) ? "" : $1
}1' File2) | tr -s ,
```

---

```
1,2,3,4,a,d,e,f
11,12,13,14,a,f,g,h
21,22,23,24,b,p,q
31,32,33,34,b,p,q
41,42,43,44,b,x,y
```

- **`paste <(commandA)` <(commandB)** will combine the outputs of two process together;
- I use **`cond ? YES : NO`** in the `awk` command instead of **`if...else...`**;
- **`tr -s`** will translate `,,` to `,`.

Comment: Please explain this command. I am aware of awk and paste utility. Thanks.

Comment: I am little aware of awk and paste utility. :-(

Comment: And this is giving incorrect output... your if/else thing worked.

Comment: Please explain your logic, as I am very little aware about awk utility.